# RichFaces 3 FileUpload on Jboss EAP 7 and JSF 1.2

Tags: java, richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating from Jboss EAP 6 to Jboss EAP 7 a JSF 1.2, Richfaces 3.3 and Prettyfaces application.

Everything seems to work nice but the RichFaces FileUpload. When I upload a file it seems to perform well but the org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest gets an empty InputStream from io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl. 
This new version of Jboss has moved to undertow as web server so I don't know if it has to do with it or with Java EE 7.

Doing the same action with Jboss EAP 6 y get my bytes.

What could be the cause of not getting the file bytes?

We cannot migrate to JSF 2.x right now.

Thanks!

Comment: RF 3 works with Servlet version 2.5, EAP 7 uses Servlet 3.0 which is not compatible (on the other hand EAP 6 should also be using 3.0 so I'm not sure how why it works fine there)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by excluding jsf subsystem.

To keep compatibility with previous version, I have this in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar"
            use-physical-code-source="true" />
    </resources>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="webservices" />
        <subsystem name="jsf" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

The `<subsystem name="jsf" />` did the trick.